# how to predict the next occurrence of an event from the previous occurrences using matlab - neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am working on a project where I have to predict the occurrence of an event, for example a certain event say E1 has occurred on 1/1/2013, 2/3/2013, 12/4/2013, 10/6/2013 and so on..  Now, how can I use/train neural network's time series tool to predict the next occurrence of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following link answer your question?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/time-series-prediction.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.. It solved most of the problem, but yet I couldn't figure out how to use this to predict the next occurrences. Any clue on how to do that.